# Android Horizontal scrollview with [10][10]

Tags: android, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, android-4.4-kitkat, horizontalscrollview

I am looking for the android horizontal `scrollview` of [10][10]array means 10 `TextViews` which should display vertically and for each respective vertical `TextView` there will be 9 more `TextView`s which will be in `Horizontal Scrollview` ..
I am not able to create a grid of [10][10] horizontal and vertical `scorllview`

Comment: Want to create a grid with both vertical and horizontal scroll capability ?

Comment: @ABFORCE yes..Vertical not necessary as ten vertical textview will come in single view but for horizontal yes..

Answer (score 0):

If you have to show 100 elements in [10][10] format with GridView then only add list of 100 elements to GridView and limit the grid view to show only 10 element per row.
 You can set limit to show 10 element a row by adding the property **android:numColumns="10"** to GridView. It will automatically set element to [10][10] format.

Example:

**1 sample_activity.xml**

```
<GridView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myGridView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:numColumns="10" />
```

**2  item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_item"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="default"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:focusable="false"/>
</TextView>

<LinearLayout>
```

**3 MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView text;
private GridView gridView;
private final String[] items = new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
        "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sample_activity);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedback);

    gridView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.myGridView);
    CustomGridAdapter gridAdapter = new CustomGridAdapter(MainActivity.this, items);
    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            text.setText((String) (gridView.getItemAtPosition(position)));
            Log.i("ITEM_CLICKED", "" + (String) (gridView.getItemAtPosition(position)));
        }
    });

}
}
```

**CustomGridAdapter**

```
public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private String[] items;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomGridAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item);
    textView.setText(items[position]);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
}
```

Comment: you mean in this gridview i should add 100 textview and then close this gridview.. did the same but this crash the code

Comment: @user3226440 you can do this programmatically

Comment: Yes, you have do this programmatically.

Comment: but I didnt get how do i add programmatically

Comment: You can add static title at start of this list. No need to use another view or table to show static titles.

Comment: @user3226440...(It helped me also) If this answer helped you to solve the issue then you need to accept it as right answer, So that other peoples also refer this answer.